# ¿Cómo buscar un archivo y si no existe añadir otra ruta?

Tags: php

Tengo dividido mi código `php` separados por cada una de sus funciones, ahora el problema es que todo lo llamo mediante la cabecera inicial `header` pero si quiero realizar pruebas donde esta los archivos separados me muestra un error por que la ruta esta especificada desde la pagina o el directorio principal.

¿Cómo puedo buscar un archivo en una ruta diferente si este existe o no mostrar otra ruta diferente?

**Ejemplo:**

```
{
// Si existe
  include_once "inc/db.php";
} else {
  //Si no existe la ruta, añadir otra ruta
  include_once "inc/confg/db.php";
}
```

Comment: Prueba con la funcion de PHP bool file_exists ( string $filename ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego un ejemplo.

```
<?php
$fichero = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($fichero)) {
    include_once "inc/db.php";
} else {
    include_once "inc/confg/db.php";
}
?>
```